# Using ajax for every div with class/id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, asp.net-core

So I have asp.net core 2 project where I have one **master view** with this html:

```
<div>
@foreach (var factory in Model.factoryList)
{
    <div class="factory-panel-content">
        <div class="factory-main-info">
            @factory.Name
            <div class="city-name">@factory.CityName</div>
            <div class="factory-some-value">
                @factory.someValue
            </div>

        </div>
        <div id="factory-plot-content">

        </div>
    </div>
}
```

And one **partial view** with (html only)

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div id="flot-line-chart" style="height: 100px"></div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
    <div id="flot-pie-chart" style="height: 100px"></div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
    <div id="gauge"></div>
</div>
```

What I need is to get partial view for every #factory-plot-content in my master view for each of my factory. 
Using ajax like below change only one of the #factory-plot-content - the first one (I understand why) but I don't know what is the best way to call ajax.get foreach of factory divs.

**My ajax:** (Which I call in master page. It will be great to call it while foreaching factories)

```
        $(document).ready(function () {

        $.ajax({
            url: '/home/ShowShortFactoryInfo',
            success: function (data) {
                $("#factory-plot-content").html(data);
            }
        });
    })
```

*The first idea I had is to make custom ids like "factory-plot-content-@Model.FactoryName" but I'm kinda sure that this is an ugly way to reach result I need.*

Comment: When and how you indent to call the `ajax()` method?

Comment: It was great if I could call it from master view in foreach operator (while I posting factory data on view)

Comment: use a class instead of an id. ID's in HTML standard are meant to be **UNIQUE**.

Comment: or use unique ids, such as `#factory-plot-content-1`, `#factory-plot-content-2` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with following code:

```
<div>
<script>
    var factoryNumber = 0;
</script>
@foreach (var factory in Model.factoryList)
{    
    <div class="factory-panel-content">
        <div class="factory-main-info">
            @factory.Name
            <div class="city-name">@factory.CityName</div>
            <div class="factory-some-value">
                @factory.someValue
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="partial-data" id="factory-plot-content">
            <script>
                getPartialData(function(data){
                    let partialData = $(".partialData")[factoryNumber];
                    partialData.html(data);
                    factoryNumber++;
                });
            </script>
        </div>
    </div>
}
<script>
function getPartialData(cb){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/home/ShowShortFactoryInfo',
        success: function (data) {
            cb(data);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: It was so dumb of me to forget that I can use <script> inside my foreach. Thank you so much for advice and solution. Your code works just fine with `let partialData = $(".partial-data").eq(factoryNumber);`. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it would be much better to use let partialData = $(".partial-data").eq(factoryNumber);  :)